# Sign of the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices with positive eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R^n)$ be two square real matrices of dimension $n$. Suppose that the eigenvalues of $A,B$ are real and strictly positive. Can $A+B$ have a strictly negative eigenvalue?

I know that if $A,B$ commute and are diagonalizable, then they are diagonalizable in a shared basis and therefore the answer to the question is negative.

However, I don’t see how to tackle the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $A=\pmatrix{1&0\cr n&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{1&n\cr 0&1}$, $A+B=\pmatrix{2&n\cr n&2}$, the polynomial characteristic of $A+B$ is $(2-X)^2-n^2=X^2-4X-n^2+4$. If $n$ is enough big, it has a negative root.

Comment: Interestingly, the eigenvalues are then simply $2\pm n$.

Answer (score 0):

it's worth noting that if this was true then every real Nilpotent matrix plus its transpose would have to be the zero matrix, i.e. every nilpotent matrix would be skew symmetric, hence normal, hence the zero matrix would be the only nilpotent matrix.

i.e. consider an arbitrary real nilpotent matrix as the limit of a sequence
$N_k:= N +\frac{1}{k}I$
so the symmetric matrix $N_k +N_k^T$ would have real non-negative eigenvalues for all $k$ which implies $N+N^T$ has no negative eigenvalues, but being symmetric and traceless $\implies N=-N^T$ for arbitrary nilpotent $N$ which is the contradiction.